# MS SQL distinct results based on other table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, linq

I want to generate a new table that shows the first and last entry of another table based on its primary key.

I have a Meter Table that contains all the `Meter Ids`

**Meter Table**

```
MeterId CostPerUnit
1    1.23
2    4.14
3    5.31
4    13.13
```

Then I have a Measurements table that does half hourly records like

**Measurement Table**

```
MeterId    StartTime    NumberOfUnits
1    2002-12-01 00:01:00    25
1    2002-12-01 00:30:00    78
1    2003-09-01 02:30:00    30
1    2008-07-02 01:00:00    15
2    1999-01-01 00:30:00    23
2    2000-03-23 05:03:00    30
2    2008-04-18 18:30:00    25
3    2006-04-03 12:00:00    30
4    2004-04-04 11:30:00    13
4    2008-09-09 15:00:00    15
```

The results table should be like this:

```
MeterId    FirstAvailability    LastAvailability
1    2002-12-01    2008-07-02
2    1999-01-01    2008-04-18
3    2006-04-03    2006-04-03
4    2004-04-04    2008-09-09
```

So:

1. Date must be unique by day (I figured that I could use `SELECT DISTINCT CAST(StartTime AS DATE)` )
2. Find the first and last entry (I figured that I could use `ORDER BY ASC` and `ORDER BY DESC` on for a particular MeterId, but not sure how to iterate all meter ids)

NOTE:
- The measurement table consists of 10 million rows with 8000 meter ids.

Comment: Date must be unique by day - I am not sure what that means, if two meters have the same start time, rule one out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Min/Max would work here.

```
SELECT
    FirstAvailability = MIN(StartTime),
    LastAvailability = MAX(StartTime)
FROM
    Measurement
GROUP BY
    MeterID
ORDER BY
    MeterID
```

Comment: It took about 3 minutes to execute this query, is it an expected speed?

Comment: That should be another question. The answer of which would depend on roughly how many records you are querying and what kind of index(es) are the fields MeterID and StartTime part of, if any. You would get better feed back asking this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

you could use aggregation functions min() max() and group by

```
    select a.MeterId, min(a.StartTime), max(StartTime)
    from Measurement 
    group by a.Meter
```

Answer (score 1):

use max(),min()

```
   select t1.meterid, convert(date,max(StartTime)) LastAvailability,
     convert(date,min(StartTime))as FirstAvailability    
     table1 t1 join table2 t2 t1.metricid=t2.metricid
    group by t1.meterid
```